# Issue with switching between UIPickerViews in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIViewController` that contains two `UITextFields` and two Picker arrays that should populate the `UIPickerViews` based on what `UITextField` is selected.

When `UITextField` `pickerTextField` is selected the `pickOption` array should populate. When `pickerTextField2` is selected the `pickerOption2` array should populate.

Currently, when the `pickerTextField` or `pickerTextField2` is selected the same arrays `pickerOption2` is being shown for both.

What is written incorrectly?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField2: UITextField!
    var textField1: UITextField?
    var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    var pickOption2 = ["two", "four", "six", "eight", "ten"]

    let pickerView = UIPickerView()

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField1 = textField
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        pickerView.isHidden = false
        return true
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerTextField.delegate = self
        pickerTextField2.delegate = self
        pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView
        pickerTextField2.inputView = pickerView

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = false
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.78, green:0.26, blue:0.26, alpha:1.0)
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneClick))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        toolBar.setItems([spaceButton, doneButton], animated: true)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        pickerTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        pickerTextField2.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    }

    @objc func doneClick() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            return pickOption.count
        }
        return pickOption2.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            return pickOption[row]
        }
        return pickOption2[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            textField1?.text = pickOption[row]
            return
        }
        textField1?.text = pickOption2[row]

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` instead of `shouldBeginEditing`? Also, check the value of `textField1` when the delegate methods are run. It might be nil.

Comment: see this code `if textField1?.tag == 10 {
            textField1?.text = pickOption[row]
            return
        }
        textField1?.text = pickOption2[row]`

Comment: Do yourself a favor and create two pickerviews - one per textfield. You're arguably saving memory at the expense of more complicated code.

Comment: You may set a flag which like `isPickerOption1 = true` to judge for your data array, I don't think it's a good idea to use the tag of UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two pickers

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerTextField2: UITextField!
    // var textField1: UITextField? - not needed
    var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    var pickOption2 = ["two", "four", "six", "eight", "ten"]

    let pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
    let pickerView2 = UIPickerView()

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // This should not be needed
    //func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // textField1 = textField
        // pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        //pickerView.isHidden = false
        // return true
    // }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView1.delegate = self
        pickerView2.delegate = self
        pickerTextField.delegate = self // This may not be needed anymore
        pickerTextField2.delegate = self // This may not be needed anymore
        pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView1
        pickerTextField2.inputView = pickerView2

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // ToolBar
       //..... all your code

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        // ... more of your code

    }

    @objc func doneClick() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }


    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView = pickerView1 {
            return pickOption.count
        }
        return pickOption2.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            return pickOption[row]
        }
        return pickOption2[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pickerView1 {
            pickerTextField.text = pickOption[row]
        } else {
            pickerTextField2.text = pickOption2[row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error, `Ambiguous reference to member 'pickerView(_:numberOfRowsInComponent:)'` for the line `pickerView.delegate = self`

Comment: @PeterDavon - did you rename the local variable to `pickerView1`? There's a typo. I fixed above

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, everything looks good. I think problem is with the setting the tag value in your storyboard, the tag value by default is 0 for both the textFields, so it is not going in `if` part and returning you the values from second array.

Try this to fix the issue,

1. Select storyboard and click on your ViewController
2. Select the pickerTextField
3. Go to Attribute Inspector from right pane
4. Set the tag value to 10
5. Build and run

Hope it helps.